# Many files - flat or tree?

Tags: performance, filesystems

My application need to keep a large amount of fairly small files (10-100k) that are usually accessed with some 'locality' in the filename's string expression.

Eg. if `file_5_5` is accessed, files like `file_4_5` or `file_5_6` may be accessed too in a short while.

I've seen that web browser file caches are often sorted in a tree like fashion resembling the lexical order of the filename, which is a kind of hash. Eg. `sadisadji` would reside at `s/a/d/i/ssadisadji` for example. I guess that is optimized for fast random access to any of these files.

Would such a tree structure be useful for my case too? Or does a flat folder keeping all files in one location does equal well?

Comment: I don't know about performance, but I know that the tree hierarchy has great benefits for simplifying your archiving/backups scripts, and for reducing the amount of work required when you later add more discs and want to move just some of the files onto them, since all you have to do is add a mount point.

Comment: Some filesystems do linear searching in directories, so having thousands of files in one directory can be very slow.

Comment: Using ext3 and ext4, the access to files in my large dirs actually is quite fast. However, `ls` may take some time...

Answer (score 0):

A tree structure would be better because many filesystems have trouble with listing a single directory with 100,000 files or more in them.

One approach taken by the .mbtiles file format, which stores a large number of image files for use with maps, is to store all of the files in an SQLite database, circumventing the problems caused by having thousands of files in a directory. Their reasoning and implementation is described here:

https://www.mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/

Comment: However, I would only rarely 'list' the directories. Usually some files inside are accessed, that does not mean listing is neccessary.

Comment: I also wonder how an sqlite DB perform, if 'tiles' are updated frequently. For my application, they would sometimes. The sqlite developers would have to solve the fragmentation issues etc. quite as well as the filesystem developers had (as least for modern systems).

Comment: A SQLite store is best for large data sets that don't change much and the added complexity probably wouldn't help you more than it hurts. Your best bet is probably going with a directory tree structure.